# Questions on the field extension $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2 − 5\rangle$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

> Given the field extension $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2 − 5\rangle$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, and letting $a = [x] ∈ K$;
>
> 1) Show $K ≃ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5) $ and $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = 2.$
>
> 2)Find the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and
>   represent the elements $a^3, (1 + a)^2, (1 + a)^{−1}$ in the form $c + da$, where $c, d ∈ \mathbb{Q}$.

I am quite lost with this question. I struggle with the basic concept of field extensions and calculating their dimesion, and amn't too sure on the form of members of the set K. There are quite a few gaps in my knowledge of this topic so I'd appreciate some clarification. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $K=\mathbb{Q[x]/\langle x^2-5 \rangle}$? What is this $a$ exactly?

Comment: Yes sorry, edited.

Comment: The elements of $K$ can be uniquely expressed as $ax+b+(x^2-5)$. Define $\phi:K\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ by $\phi(ax+b+(x^2-5))=a\sqrt{5}+b$. Prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @HatMan Why is it that the elements of $K$ can be expressed that way?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, the Euclidean algorithm lets me do that.

Comment: Oh I think I understand. I was trying to account for the higher powers of x, but they're all in the $(x^2−5)$ part, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Notice that $\alpha = \sqrt{5}$ is a root of $f(x) = x^2 - 5$. Now take any $g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and divide it by $f (x)= x^2-5$. What is the remainder? Next, take $g(\alpha)$, and notice that it can be written in terms of $a + b\alpha$.
- Use the Eiseinstein Criterion to determine whether $f(x) = x^2-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, from this conclude that the ideal $\langle f(x)\rangle$ is maximal.
- To see that $K \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, use the [Isomophism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem).

Feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: Could you state explicitly the form of the elements of K, for clarity?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) = \lbrace a + b\sqrt{5} ; a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$. There you go.

Comment: I can vaguely see the logic in showing $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ but I just don't understand what a field extension actually is.

Comment: Are we sort of adding the set of multiples of $\sqrt5$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Did you follow the steps? What you are doing is adjointing an algebraic element to the field $\mathbb{Q}$. If an element is  algbraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite and it's dimension is determined by the degree of of its minimal polynomial.

Comment: @user123454321 You may see the field extension as a vector space which basis is $\lbrace 1,\alpha \rbrace $. Then every element can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the basis.

Comment: So, any progress?

Comment: Not quite, I'm unsure as to how I apply the isomorphism theorem. And again, given my ineptitude with this branch of maths I'm struggling with various definitions and whys of your method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18900/discussion-between-aaron-maroja-and-123454321).